# How do I make a disperse-like effect?

Tags: c#, physics, point

I am creating a project in Visual Studio 2015 where I a planet picturebox and a star picture box. The planet is rotating around the star in a timer, updating every 100ms. Here is the code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    float angle = 0;
    float rotSpeed = 1;
    Point point = new Point(253, 151);
    int distance = 200;

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if (star.Visible) { // star is a picturebox
        angle += rotSpeed;
        int x = (int)(point.X + distance * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180));
        int y = (int)(point.Y + distance * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180));
        planet.Location = new Point(x, y);
       }
         else {
        // What do i put here so that when the star disappears, the planet
        // infinitely drifts off in the direction it was going?
       }
   }
```

So the planet is orbiting the star, and I want to make a simulation that the planet drifts off into space when the star disappears.

Pretty much, what would happen if a star disappeared in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the star disappears, Newton's first law kicks in, which says that the velocity is constant. So, what is the velocity? There's a nice 'trick' you can use, namely the velocity is the derivative of position with respect to time, so

```
vx = distance * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * rotSpeed * Math.PI / 180
vy = -distance * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * rotSpeed * Math.PI / 180
```

where we used that `d/dt angle = rotSpeed`.

Therefore, we simply need to update its position based on its constant velocity:

```
x0 = point.X + distance * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)
y0 = point.Y + distance * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180)
x = x0 + driftTicks * vx
y = y0 + driftTicks * vy
```

where `driftTicks` is the number of 'ticks', that is the number of times `timer1_Tick` is called, when the sun is gone. It starts at `0` and is increased by `1` each time the `else` clause triggers.

---

Note: if you want to do this in a more flexible and extensible way, the usual recourse is to save the `x` and `y` position at the moment the sun disappears, rather than recalculating it every time, and use these saved values for `x0` and `y0`.